# Unable to access read function in FILEREADER class when using Generic class. Can anybody please let me know why I can't access read function here?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, filereader, java-io

Unable to access read function in FILEREADER class when using Generic class. Can anybody please let me know why I can't access read function here?

**Main class:**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class MainIO {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside mainIO class");
    FileReader fr = null;
    GenericInput gio;
    try {
      fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\alex\\IdeaProjects\\javaIO\\src\\inputfile.txt");
      gio = new GenericInput(fr);
      gio.readByteData(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**2nd class:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GenericInput < T > {
  T input;
  public GenericInput(T input) {
    System.out.println("Inside: " + input.getClass().getName());
    this.input = input;
  }
  public void readByteData(T input) throws Exception {
    int c;
    while ((c = input.read()) != -1)
      System.out.print(c + "-");
  }
}
```

**Input text file:**

```
pythön
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\alex\IdeaProjects\javaIO\src\GenericInput.java:14:25
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method read()
  location: variable input of type T
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `<T>` is not constrained, it can be anything - even an `Object` or an `Integer`, so there's no guarantee it will have a `read` method. If you want to use that method, you need to constrain `T` to something that has such a method - e.g., something that extends a [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html):

```java
public class GenericInput <T extends Reader> {
// Here ---------------------^
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked @Mureinik. But I'm trying to create a generic class for both InputStream and Reader class where the same read () function is accessible. So, that I can use a single Generic class while creating the objects for them. Assuming both InputStream & Reader class are child class of object. So, instead of extending Reader class, can I extend some other which is parent to both InputStream and FileReader parent class .